# Why does ant ignore task jars in $HOME/.ant/lib/

Tags: java, linux, ant

**Configuration:**  I'm running stock Fedora 12 with the ant that Fedora ships:

- ant-1.7.1-12.fc12
- java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-33.b16.fc12

I have `svnant.jar` and `svnClientAdapter.jar` in my `$HOME/.ant/lib/`

I'm using the following `build.xml`:

```
<project name="antlibtest" default="doEcho">
    <taskdef resource="svntask.properties"/>

    <target name="doEcho">
        <echo message="Hello World!"/>
        <echo message="ANT_HOME=${ant.home}"/>
        <echo message="classpath=${java.class.path}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

When the build file is executed, I get the following error:
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource svntask.properties. It could not be found.

If I set ANT_HOME to `/usr/share/ant/` it works flawlessly.

In both cases, the jars from my home directory are clearly in the output of the classpath.

How do I make this work without resorting to my own copy of ant, ANT_HOME and ant --noconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the problem described in [Bug 490542](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=490542) (that applies to Fedora 12 too according to the last comment). Sadly, the bug is still in a NEW state so I don't think it will be solved in a near future.

Regarding ANT_HOME, doesn't `/etc/ant.conf` set it to `/usr/share/ant` as explained [here](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#InstantiationException)? This may be outdated but I can't check it (and I don't really get how this should be setup on Fedora).

Comment: Thanks! I've looked at the bash scripts driving ant, and the trailing slash in my ANT_HOME seems to be the reason for it working in that case.  It does not work if ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant

Comment: Ohoh. So setting `ANT_HOME` to `/usr/share/ant/` in `/etc/ant.conf` would solve this?

Comment: For the most part it seems to.  There's some sort of wrong matching in the bash scripts that handle Ant's initialization on Linux

Comment: Setting ANT_HOME to /usr/share/ant/ (adding the trailing slash) solved it for me.

Comment: The bug is still there in CentOS 7.7. Setting this var in /etc/ant.conf did not work for me. Had to add `export ANT_HOME='/usr/share/ant/'` in  `~/.bashrc` .

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem with maven-ant-tasks.jar. Ant showed the jar file in the classpath but didn't find it in the  tag. The change of ANT_HOME didn't work for me, but I found another solution:

The optional jar files have to be registered in a simple text file in /etc/ant.d containing the name (or path) of the jar file, where the path is relative to /usr/share/java and without the extension ".jar".

So if you want to register maven-ant-tasks for example, then simply put maven-ant-tasks.jar (or it's symlink) into /usr/share/java and add the file "maven-ant-tasks" to /etc/ant.d consisting of the line: "maven-ant-tasks".

That works at least for me on openSuse 11.1. Maybe this helps somebody.

Hannes

Answer (score 0):

I get same issue on centos 7 google cloud build-in ant is 1.9.x
I try to download newest ant 1.10.x but have same issue

Setting `ANT_HOME` to `/usr/share/ant/` also resolve it.